# How to redirect to new component version?

Tags: .net, devexpress

So I am in the process of taking over a lot of code from a consulting business (bringing it inhouse). They have written some DLLs that is used across projects. In some of these DLLs they reference a third-party component (DevExpress).

So far so good.

I can download the DevExpress bits and all is wonderful. However there is one issue: The DLL is compiled against an old version of DevExpress (10.2 vs. 11.1). And the DevExpress component is named according to version:

> Old: 'DevExpress.XtraReports.v10.2, Version=10.2.4.0'
>
> New: 'DevExpress.XtraReports.v11.1, Version=11.1.7.0'

So not only do I need to 'redirect' the version, but also the name. The error is showing up at compile time.

Is this solvable?

Comment: Compile time? Do you mean you have the source code for these dlls?

Comment: Nope, not the DevExpress DLL or the common code DLL.

Comment: @noocyte: If you can get the source code, you can just use the update tool from devexpress and re-compile the projects. It will update all your references for you in all your projects to the latest version installed on your computer. If not, you will need to download the same version of the devexpress libraries and use that version with your current solution.

Comment: I did get the source code and recompiled. all is well now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the project converter which is designed for this. It is located under the Windows Start Menu at "Develper Express V2011 vol1 -> Components -> Tools -> Project Converter". This will automatically change all of your references to the current version.

[Project Converter Documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#ProjectConverter/CustomDocument2529)

Comment: You need the source code for this I assume. So not really a valid option before I had the source code... :)